# plotly candlestick in python

Tags: python, plotly

Montei um gráfico de candlestick usando o `plotly` e gostaria de saber se é possível criar em cima desse gráfico, se baseando na coluna `flag` que contém o número 1, um retângulo que sobrepõe os candlesticks.

Exemplo do código:

```
import pandas as pd   
import plotly.graph_objects as go  

df = pd.DataFrame({"data_minu": ['30/10 09:00','30/10 09:05','30/10 09:10','30/10 09:15','30/10 09:20','30/10 09:25','30/10 09:30','30/10 09:35','30/10 09:40','30/10 09:45'],`insira o código aqui`
                   "Open":['10','17','23','20','8','22','24','25','29','22'],
                   "High":['21','27','25','29','24','27','28','32','29','25'],
                   "Low":['6','12','18','9','5','8','24','18','15','10'],
                   "Close":['17','24','22','10','21','25','26','30','18','10'],
                   "Flag": ['0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','0']})   

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['data_minu'],
                open=df['Open'], high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'], close=df['Close'])
                     ])

fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)  
fig.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado atual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

blz.  O pessoal do site do plotly me ajudou com essa dúvida. Compartilho com vcs o link da resposta. Não é a mesma coisa, porém fica facil fazer os ajustes na ideia inicial.

https://community.plot.ly/t/plotly-candlestick-in-python-with-flag/31154

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data_minu": ['30/10 09:00','30/10    
 09:05','30/10,09:10','30/10 09:15','30/10 09:20','30/10 09:25','30/10  
 09:30','30/10 09:35','30/10 09:40','30/10 09:45'],
                   "Open":['10','17','23','20','8','22','24','25','29','22'],
                   "High":['21','27','25','29','24','27','28','32','29','25'],
                   "Low":['6','12','18','9','5','8','24','18','15','10'],
                   "Close":['17','24','22','10','21','25','26','30','18','10'],
                   "Flag": ['0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','0']})     

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=tickvals, #df['data_minu'],
                open=df['Open'], high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'], close=df['Close'])
                     ])  

tickvals =[k*0.5 for k in range(len(df))]
ticktext=list(df["data_minu"])
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False, xaxis_tickvals=tickvals, xaxis_ticktext=ticktext) 
for k, flag in  enumerate(df['Flag']):
    if int(flag):
        fig.add_shape(dict(type='rect',
                          xref='x', yref='y',  
                          layer='below',   
                          x0 = tickvals[k]-0.2, y0 = float(df.loc[k, 'Low'])-1,  
                          x1 = tickvals[k]+0.2, y1 = float(df.loc[k, 'High'])+1,  
                          fillcolor='orange', #'RoyalBlue',  
                          opacity=0.35))
```